# Multiple declarations same of variables inside and outside for loop

Tags: c, variable-declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        int i = 10;
        printf ( "%d", i );
        i++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

In this variable `i` is declared outside the `for` loop and it is again declared and initialized inside `for` loop. How does C allows multiple declarations?

Comment: Even if you have `for (int i=0; i<5; i++ )` the next `i` has nested scope. But I don't like it, the language feature is not intended to be used to recycle variable names. Always use creative variable names that do not conflict or shadow.

Comment: See _inner scope/outer scope_ C11 §6.2.1 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `i` outside the loop and the `i` inside the loop **are two different variables**.

- The outer `i` will live for the entire duration of `main`.
- The inner `i` will only live for the duration of one loop iteration.

The inner one [*shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer one in this scope:

```
{
    int i = 10;
    printf ( "%d", i );
    i++;
}
```

Due to shadowing rules, it is impossible to refer to the outer one while inside the aforementioned scope.

---

Note that it is  impossible to declare two variables with the same name **in the same scope**:

```
{
    int i = 0;
    int i = 1; // compile-time error
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terminology the C standard uses is “hides” rather than “shadows.”

Answer (score 3):

Variables in one scope can **mask** variables at a higher scope.

In this example, the `i` defined inside of the loop masks the `i` defined outside.  In the loop body, the `printf` prints the value of the inner `i`, which is 10.  The `i++` then operates again on the inner `i` setting it to 11.

When the loop hits the bottom and goes back up, the inner `i` goes out of scope.  The second and third clauses of the `for` then operate on the outer `i`.  When the loop body is entered again, a new instance of the inner `i` is defined and initialized to 10.

Comment: FYI, the terminology the C standard uses is “hides” rather than “masks.”

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the following page for the definitions of the different type of scopes that variables can have in the C language.

http://aelinik.free.fr/c/ch14.htm

Your first `int i` is in the scope of the entire block, and your second `int i` only has scope from within that nested loop. Once outside the nested loop, the original block scope version of `i` is applicable again.